# Getting undefined error while reading in array in For loop

Tags: typescript

Here is the array:
[ [ { code: 'PTL', coverage: [Object] }, { code: 'DAO', coverage: [Object] } ] ]

I think my code is getting undefined when I checking Code = DAO and then trying to get inside the coverage which is not visible.

Comment: How I can unhide the object in coverage?

Answer (score 0):

You're having an array of arrays of objects.

```js
var arr = [ [ { code: 'PTL', coverage: {} }, { code: 'DAO', coverage: {} } ] ]

// This won't work, as coverage does not exist here:
arr[0].coverage

// This should work:
arr[0][0].coverage
```